# How to fix 'The application "..." can't be opened' on Mac?

Tags: macos, chmod

I get this:

[image: dialog box]

Some people said use `chmod` to fix the execution files thing, but I still don't understand how to do it. Can some one tell me step by steps please?

Comment: Can you provide the path to the application? Where exactly on your filesystem is it?

Comment: I've seen this once in  a while.  A reboot will clear it in many cases.  I haven't dug into the exact cause.

Comment: @Fanatique it's in application section

Comment: Using "The Unarchiver" to unzip the application worked for me (regular Archive Utility bundled with macOS Catalina did *not*  -- see Dmitriy Pavlukhin's answer below!)

Comment: @JamonHolmgren the Unarchiver thing did the trick.. not even the `zip` command worked.

Comment: If you're using an Apple M1 or M2 chip, Big Sur added extra security so that native ARM64 code can't be executed, which the app you're trying to open may very well be made in. You can bypass this though by codesigning the app. Assuming the app is in your application folder: `codesign --force --deep -s - /Applications/AppName.app`

Answer (score 32):

In my case nothing helped until I accidently opened context menu on .zip file.
Open With -> there were

1) Archive Utility (default) which always broke my app when unzipped

2) The Unarchiver, unzipped with this and application started

OS 10.14

Comment: Can you describe your solution more accurately? I have been fighting this problem for 3 days :( On some MAC's, application runs without a problem on others (especially new ones) gets information as in the subject

Comment: @user1100353 just try another archive managing utilities. In my case standart Unarchiver which was installed in system helped.

Comment: unzipped with unzip command and it worked.

Comment: This worked, thank you Dmitriy!

Comment: The Unarchiver works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, what possible explanation can there be for this? How can one program break the app, while the other does not? I just experienced this first hand.

Comment: My suggestion is that Archive Utility doesn't know how to work with hidden and meta files being in that archive.

Answer (score 29):

This happens because the application doesn't have execution permissions.

To make the application executable:

1. Open a terminal window (CMD + Space -> terminal);
2. Using the `cd` command, navigate to the place where the application is stored: `cd <path_to_application>`
3. Run `chmod +x <application_file>` to make it executable. If it doesn't let you, sudo it:
   `sudo chmod +x <application>`.

The command from point 3 should look similar to this (thanks to @CJK):

```
chmod +x "/Applications/ShadowBat.app/Contents/MacOS/ShadowBat"
```

Comment: Just to clarify by example for the OP, your command should look something like this: `chmod +x "/Applications/ShadowBat.app/Contents/MacOS/ShadowBat"`, adding `sudo` at the start if needed.

Comment: Thank you @CJK. Not an OSX user, so didn't have an idea. Will add that to my post.

Comment: when I type: cd <path_to application>, it load: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'. what should I do?

Comment: and when I type like: chmod +x "/Applications/ShadowBat.app/Contents/MacOS/ShadowBat" it load: No such file or directory.

Comment: Not working anymore with MacOS 10.14 Mojave.

Comment: Interesting: when I do the `chmod +x ...`, the app does fail with a new error under macOS 10.15 Catalina: `[app-name] is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Bin.`

Comment: Recursive (-R option) if it still doesn't work: `chmod -R +x "/Applications/ShadowBat.app/Contents/MacOS/ShadowBat"`

Comment: Worked just fine for me, have an upvote

Answer (score 4):

@Fanatique is right, but be advised -

There are many possible causes for this problem, and most *cannot* be fixed using `chmod`. Handling program bundles with inappropriate tools often will "damage" executable bundles.

- Making zip or tar archives with inappropriate settings  will strip many file attributes;
- copying via different file systems - e.g. a FAT32 formatted USB stick - might ruin file names (capitalization, special characters);
- finally, copying applications between computers with the correct tools might result in invalid "receipt" files (sometimes commercial apps are cryptographically locked to certain hardware ids that way - the receipt will not be valid on the destination machine).

You shouldn't use `chmod` unless you have a good understanding of both file modes and ACLs, and more important, *of what **exactly** the problem is*, so you can fix it... this innocuous tool is well capable of recursively ruining your whole filesystem (and may even keep your system from booting).

If in doubt, I'd recommend deleting and reinstalling the pertaining app.

Comment: I did and it didn't work

Comment: I put it in the application section

Answer (score 2):

The following command typically solves most issues:

```
chmod +x "/Applications/ShadowBat.app/Contents/MacOS/ShadowBat"
```

but if it doesn't, there may be another application file within the application that you need to run the same command for. For example, right click the application and click "Show Package Contents" then look for a folder called "Versions".

There may be another application within this folder that you can follow the same process for the command above to make the application executable.